# Convert Blob data and how to send the audio files details to API?

Tags: node.js, angular

**Requirement:** Working on audio recorder module, using record rct, audio is been recorder and data is in blob format Blob {size: 360492, type: 'audio/wav'}, I have create a api using content-type=multipart/form data and req.files (using postman I use to get the data of audio file(buffer data inside it) and store the audio file in s3.

**Doubt:**

1. how to convert the blob in angular and send the audio file data to node api?

Im using Angular 13 and node API

**I tried: **

```
`  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', this.teste.blob,this.teste.title);
  
  var dee = formData.get('file')

  console.log(dee)`
```

Console: I am getting this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNjFI.png)

here i didnt get any buffer or base64 data of audio? Is there any way to get the audio file buffer or base64 data and send to API.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert blob to file before send to your api

```
const file = new File([blob], "test.wav", {lastModified: Date.now});

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);
  
  // send this file right now
```

read more here

https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI

Comment: same file is printed in console which i attached as an image in question, i cant see any base64 or buffer data of the audio.

Comment: can you provide upload code to let us know where the problem

Comment: File {name: 'test.wav', lastModified: 1675915454156, lastModifiedDate: Thu Feb 09 2023 09:34:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 1425452, …}
lastModified
: 
1675915454156
lastModifiedDate
: 
Thu Feb 09 2023 09:34:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
name
: 
"test.wav"
size
: 
1425452
type
: 
""
webkitRelativePath
: 
""

Comment: As you suggested i have appended the blob to form data and sent to api, In API req.files i cant see any audio buffer data its empty what i should do now??rapidReaderLib.audioUploadData(req.body,req.files, req.models,req.session, (data) => {
            return res.status(data.status_code).json(data)
        });